# Prevent users from editing master branch in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to prevent developers from directly editing and committing to the master branch in ADF.

There is a risk that users can accidently make changes in ADF by not creating a feature branch but instead working directly on master (I've done it myself!)

Is there a way to enforce this in ADF? I do have a branch policy on master that only allows merging via a pull request but don't think this stops developers from working directly on master:

[image]

Comment: Git has no such controls; Azure probably does, but that's up to Azure, not Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is to require a reviewer.

Select "Branch policies":

[image]

Turn on the option "Require a minimum number of reviewers":

[image]

Set the number of reviewers to 1.

This example shows "Allow requestors to approve their own changes". This setting is optional. If you set it, the user is still prevented from committing to main/master, but can complete their own PRs.

Answer (score 0):

You can deny the contribute permission for the user group in git repo. Check the following official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops